# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: waves (found in <I18n> at src/views/backend/areachange/Index.vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

[image]

I am using https://element.eleme.io/#/ 
I am facing in every listing pages

Answer (score 1):

```js
Vue.directive('custom', {
  inserted: function(el) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'orange'
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-custom type="text">
  <input v-waves type="text">
  <!-- The `v-waves` directive will have the same error -->
</div>
```

The reason is that there is no custom directive registered. For more usage of custom directives, [please see here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html).